# Why is this happen when I am running my programm?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I am new to this software which is Borland C++, and now im trying to run my own project but why is this appear when im running the programm?

[image: Program 1]

[image: Program 2]

Comment: Let's see your program, not an image of your output.  Also, why are you using such an old compiler, something from the last generation?

Comment: I am learning using this old vers. software because my lecturer ask me to using it.And it sucks when im trying to search the answer from the internet..the answ given can only be applied to the new vers. software..

Comment: My recommendation: switch to a good C++11 compiler such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). Both are open source so freely downloadable (on Windows, consider [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/); On Linux or MacOSX, you'll find packages). Provide some [mre] in your question (not as a link to some external image) Read [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info: with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`; read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book and some [C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). Consider installing some Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](http://debian.org/)) on your laptop after having backed up your most important data

Comment: Once your C++ code works with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [porting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) it to Borland C++ is a few minutes of work (adding some `#ifdef`...)

Comment: Don't forget to use [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) on your C++ source code.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the data types are wrong.  It is printing out the student ID as a floating point number (such as 5.6  or 1.44E09) yet the underlying data is not floating point.  For instance:

```
int student = 53;
printf ( "Student ID = %f\n", student );   // WRONG
```

The student number is an integer "int", yet in the print instruction (in this example) it is telling the computer to print as a floating point (the %f)   To print an int, you must use %d:

```
int student = 53;
printf ( "Student ID = %d\n", student );
```

Use %f for floating point numbers:

```
int student = 53;
float  gradeAverage = 3.6; 
printf ( "Student ID = %d  grade=%f\n", student, gradeAverage);
```

Comment: It this is your guess as to the issue, you should advise using `cout` instead of `printf`.  Then the data type issue becomes a moot point.